# How to connect to my cluster on aws which has private topology and internal loadbalacer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, kops, internal-load-balancer, amazon-elb

I am creating a cluster using the following command:

> kops create cluster --zones us-west-1c --master-size=m4.large --node-size=m5.large ${NAME} --associate-public-ip=false --topology private --api-loadbalancer-type internal --networking calico --vpc vpc-xxxxxxxx --cloud-labels="Creator=revor,Description=YM k8 cluster,ENV=int,Name=SMV_INT_YMK8,Requestor=Rey Reymond,code=5483"

The cluster gets created in aws. So far so good. But the problem is, when I run `kops validate cluster` I get:

> Validating cluster xxx.xxx.xx
>   unexpected error during validation: error listing nodes: Get https://api. xxx.xxx.xx/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 172.30.xx.xx:443: getsockopt: connection refused

and when I run `kubectl get nodes` I get:

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 172.30.xx.xx:443: i/o timeout

Also when I run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa admin@api.xxx.xxx.xx` I get:

> sh: connect to host api. xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection refused

My question is why I cannot connect to my cluster and why I'm getting the above errors?

As the above command shows, my cluster is defined to have a private topology and no public IP addresses and an internal loadbalancer. I'm wondering if that mean I should not be able to connect to my cluster and the above errors are expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your instances are private, that is expected. I bet your `xxx.xxx.xx` is in some private IP range like `172.x.x.x`. The usual approach to this is to create an EC2 instance with public IP address in a public network, connect to this instance and then connect to your private instances from this public instance. Such instance is generally referred to as *bastion host*. You will, of course, have to modify VPC security groups to allow access from your public subnet to your private subnet.

Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/welcome.html for AWS-provided guides.

Comment: Thank you. I created a bastion instance and I'm able to ssh nto the bastion and then from there ssh to the cluster instances. Now I'm looking for a way to run kubectl commands or "kops validate cluster" command against my cluster. When I ssh into the master node from the bastion, I am able to run kubectl commands and it works fine. But how can I connect to my cluster (using kubectl commands) from my local machine?

Comment: @samanta if you wish to use kubectl directly from you PC you need to avoid using internal ELB, you need to migrate to external ELB.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @Sergey Kovalev has mentioned, please make sure that you have your kubeconfig configured properly(in your bastion host) to have your "kubectl" connected to your kube master api